# Implementing ESP32 OTA when target and programmer are on different networks

Tags: android, ota

Arduino OTAs and Elegant OTA are very simple when both ends are connected to the same router.
In my case the target is an agricultural machine on a remote site with no router available. So I plan to connect ESP32 WiFi to a cell phone Wifi hotspot to perform an OTA update.
But I dont know how to make a port forwarding in Android environment.
VPNs can be a solution, but I would force my customers to another subscription fee.
Thanks for your help,
Horacio